# BigQuery file export quota

Tags: google-bigquery

The BigQuery documentation states various limits and quotas, however many seem to be "negotiable". I am specifically interested in the limit of 50 file exports per project per day. Is this a hard limit? If not, what is the practical limit and what does it take to get it raised?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always contact the sales team, for above the average requests: https://cloud.google.com/contact

They'll be happy to work out a solution with you!